# Differental equation, separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve following problem

$$
    u_{tt}=u_{xx}+3u_{t}
$$
$$
    u(0,x)=f(x)
$$
$$
    u(t,0)=u(t,\pi)=0
$$
I've started in this way
$$
    u(t,x)=X(x)T(t)
$$
$$
    \frac{T''(t)-3T'(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\lambda
$$
$$ \lambda=-k^2 $$ $$ X(x)=sin(kx) $$
But here I've stoped, I don't know how should I solve following equation

$$ T''(t) -3T'(t)+k^2T(t)=0$$
or maybe is there any other clever way to solve it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have to classify this equation: it is a second degree, homogenuous and linear ode, with constant coefficients. Therefore we assume solutions of the form $e^{\mu t}$ and by substitution we get the so called characteristic polynomial $\mu^2-3\mu+k^2=0$ (note that $k$ is an integer, by solving the Sturm - Liouville problem $Χ''-\lambda X=0,~X(0)=X(\pi)=0$ of the variable $x$). Τhe solutions of the above equation are $\mu_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}(3\pm \sqrt{9-4k^2})$, which gives us the solutions $$e^{\mu_1 t},~e^{\mu_2 t},~\mu_1=\frac{1}{2}(3- \sqrt{5})< \mu_2=\frac{1}{2}(3+ \sqrt{5})$$ for the case $k=1$ (where $\mu$ is real) and the solutions $e^{3/2t}\cos(\sqrt{k^2-9/4}),~e^{3t/2}\sin(\sqrt{k^2-9/4})$ for the case $k=2,3,\ldots$ (where $\mu = \frac{1}{2}(3\pm i\sqrt{4k^2-9})= 3/2\pm i\sqrt{k^2-9/4})$ is complex). Now we have to add all the solutions of the form $u_k=X_kT_k, k\geq 1$, i.e. $$e^{\mu_1 t}\sin x,~e^{\mu_2 t}\sin x$$ and $$e^{3/2t}\cos(\sqrt{k^2-9/4})\sin(kx),~e^{3t/2}\sin(\sqrt{k^2-9/4})\sin(kx),~k\geq 2$$ (with coefficients of apperarence $A,~B,~A_k,~B_k$ in the general solution respectively, say $E_k$ for convenience for now) and obtain the general solution $\displaystyle u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}E_ku_k(x,t)$. Setting $t=0$ gives us 
$$A\sin x+B\sin x +A_k\sin(kx)+B_k\sin(kx)=f(x)$$ and by arguments of orthogonability on $[0,\pi]$ we obtain the unknown coefficients.